# Regex expression in Python to match text after words and between angle brackets

Tags: python, regex

Given this string: 
`"Group <stuffhere> User <IwantThis> IP <notimportant> Address <IalsoWantThis> assigned"`,

How do I extract the things in brackets after 'User' and Address.
That is I would like to take the above string and return

```
(IwantThis, IalsoWantThis)
```

Comment: Do you actually have these brackets in your data, or are they just placeholders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it'll match all the text between `<>`:

```
s = "Group <stuffhere> User <IwantThis> IP <notimportant> Address <IalsoWantThis> assigned"
ans = re.findall(r'<(.+?)>', s)
```

Now it's easy to extract the parts that we're interested in:

```
ans[1]
=> 'IwantThis'
ans[3]
=> 'IalsoWantThis'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex could look like this

```
"Group .*? User (.*?) IP .*? Address (.*?) assigned"
```

Here, `.*?` means "as few characters as possible, but as many as are necessary so the rest fits". Also, it covers *any* character (including whitespace etc.). The parts you want are grouped using `()`. You can then do

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = "Group .*? User (.*?) IP .*? Address (.*?) assigned"
>>> match = re.match(regex, data)
```

If `match` is not `None`, the pattern matches and you can access the groups using `match.groups`:

```
>>> IwantThis, IalsoWantThis = match.groups()
```

Note that **if your data actually contains the brackets** (I assumed them to be placeholders), you will need to replace `(.*?)` with `<(.*?)>`, so that the brackets are not matched. This is not necessary for the non-grouped parts (those that are only `.*?` without parenthesis) because their data is never queried.

**If, and only if**, your values (`<stuffhere>`, `<IwantThis>`, `<notimportant>` and `<IalsoWantThis>`) do **not** contain spaces, you need not use regex and can use `string.split` instead:

```
>>> split_string = data.split()
>>> IwantThis = split_string[3]
>>> IalsoWantThis = split_string[7]
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is just an alternative to what the person before me already said

```
import re
searchText = "Group <stuffhere> User <IwantThis> IP <notimportant> Address <IalsoWantThis> assigned"
result = re.sub(".*User\\s+<([^>]+).*Address\\s+<([^>]+).*", "\\1 \\2", searchText)
print(result)
```

The regex expression here is

```
.*User\s+<([^>]+).*Address\s+<([^>]+).*
```

Edit: if you want to return tuple, try this:

```
result2 = re.findall(".*User\\s+<([^>]+).*Address\\s+<([^>]+).*", searchText)
print(result2[0])
```